# Tomcat errors, reasons JAR not included in build

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jar

When I try to deploy my Spring application to Tomcat, it gives me errors (localhost-{date}.log) saying I'm missing commons-pool-{version}.jar.

However, the source code is part of a STABLE release.  I'm using maven to build and I've successfully built and deployed this project successfully (earlier today, in fact).  So something must have changed locally. I added commons-pool-{version}.jar to my CLASSPATH, and that did not work.  I've ensured the code hasn't changed by doing a fresh checkout.

My localhost log file says

```
Sep 15, 2010 11:15:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
...
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/pool/impl/GenericObjectPool
```

My catalina log file says

```
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Sep 15, 2010 11:15:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/app] startup failed due to previous errors
```

Are there any additional settings I'm overlooking?  What else could it be?  I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1):

You can check whats on your webapp classpath by opening your war file as a zip and inspecting the `WEB-INF/lib` directory.  You should see a version of commons-pool in there.  You can use [IZArc](http://www.izarc.org/index.html) (freeware) to open archive files.

Answer (score 0):

You can either add the missing jar files in your:

WebApp **WEB-INF/lib** directory,
or 
**TomcatHome/lib** directory (please note that this jar will be loaded for all your webapps if placed here).

If you feel really extreme you can add the required jars to your **Java CLASS_PATH**.

Cool.

Comment: Also check that the requested class files are in the jar file you are using.